# ¿Cómo desactivar Submit en asp:ImageButton?

Tags: asp.net

Estoy trabajando con `VB.NET` ,tengo un `GridView` el cual defino sus columnas con `ItemTemplate`, el asunto es que tengo un control `asp:ImageButton`, para la función de eliminar con una imagen.
El problema es que ASP, deja automaticamente este Button como submit, es decir si presiono la tecla `Enter`, me hace el submit del formulario y quiero desactivar esto.

Sé que con la propiedad

```
UseSubmitBehavior ="false"
```

para los controles `Button`, me desactiva el submit que deja por defecto, pero esta propiedad no es utilizable en ImageButton.

¿Como lo puedo desactivar, que al presionar Enter no haga un submit del form?

PD: No quiero desactivar el `Enter` del `form` completo, ya que necesito capturarlo en un `input` determinado.

Comment: ¿Qué versión de asp.net utilizas?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza si te refieres a framework es 3.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el tag `form` se puede definir mediante la propiedad `defaultbutton` cual es el boton que actuara cuando presiones `enter`

[ASP.NET 2.0 - Enter Key - Default Submit Button](https://web.archive.org/web/20200924062349/http://geekswithblogs.net/ranganh/archive/2006/04/12/74951.aspx)

Pero usando javascript puede deshabilitar esta funcionalidad

[How To: Disable Form Submit on Enter Key Press](http://www.bloggingdeveloper.com/post/Disable-Form-Submit-on-Enter-Key-Press.aspx)

[How To Disable Enter Key On Forms](https://web.archive.org/web/20210625090004/https://www.paulund.co.uk/how-to-disable-enter-key-on-forms)

**>>tengo la duda en que evento controlar, ya que el imagebutton, no puedo utilizar el evento keypress**

Si usas por jquery veras que el keypress aplica sobre el tag `form`

```
$("form").keypress(function(e) { ...
```

o sea anulas los enter (seria el valor 13 que lo representa) de todo el form

Comment: en el tag form no puedo, utilizo MasterPages. estoy tratando de desactivarlo con Javascript, pero tengo la duda en que evento controlar, ya que el imagebutton, no puedo utilizar el evento keypress, porque tendria que estar sobre el imagebutton y luego presionar enter para que me tome el key. (aunque tengo dudas en esto último).

Comment: Finalmente utilice, el evento keypress para el form, muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

Otra forma en que podrías obtener este comportamiento es no utilizar `<asp:ImageButton>`, en su lugar puedes utilizar esto:

```
<button runat="server" 
    style="background-image:url('/ruta/de/tu/imagen.png')">
</button>
```

Comment: con el ImageButton, le asigno la propiedad de CommandName, para poder eliminar la fila, ya que para eso utilizo ese tipo de control, y me es más fácil capturar la fila en el codebehind y procesar los datos.